# SonarQube detect XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: java, jsp, security, sonarqube, xss

I'm trying to set up rules to detect XSS (cross-site-scripting) vulnerabilities in JSP files with SonarQube. I've searched the documentation and Google but can't find any specifics. Do I have to code my own custom rule or is there a setting somewhere? I'm new to SonarQube and still learning.

The main XSS vulnerability I'm trying to detect is when the `<c:out>` tag isn't used where it should be, like in this image:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. It's a plugin you have to install.

Comment: Can you specify in your answer which plugin it is?

Comment: I'd like to know which plugin it is as well. Can you guys mention which plugin it is?